# How to find sheet names of password protected excel file

Tags: r

Is there a way to detect the sheet names in password protected excel file?

Background:
I receive some password protected excel (.xlsx) files which often have slightly different sheet names (e.g. - could be "Total" or "totals" or "Sums", etc.) and the sheets are not in the same order in each file so I can't directly use the sheet order alone.
I would also like to be able to detect if an excel file *requires* a password (so I could modify my generic script to read & alter the data to be able to prompt only IF a password is required).

For non-password protected files I have used something like this (i.e. - compare a grepped part of the possible sheet names against the sheet names detected in the file using excel_sheets):

```
SheetNameGrep <- "otal|Sum|ums"
SheetName <- grep(SheetNameGrep, excel_sheets(filename), value = TRUE)
```

However, the excel_sheets function apparently can't handle password protected files.

I have also used xl.read.file to read password protected files like this:

```
PW <- rstudioapi::askForPassword(paste("Password Protected File: ", File ))
     
Import_Full <- xl.read.file(File, xl.sheet = SheetName, password = PW)
```

Although that appears to work if there isn't a password (i.e. - if PW = "" when the file doesn't have a password), that would require either that I get prompted for every file or to add an argument to the script to indicate whether I should be prompted (which I would like to avoid but may be my only option).

NOTE: storing the passwords in a static file or in the script itself is not an option.

Thank you.